# How to use view from external application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a web application (Firstapplication) write in .net core 2.1 and that works fine.
I now want to add views on run time from dll file created by another application.
i want to take "SeconApplication.web.Views.dll" and place it in a folder in my Fyrstapplication and whan i call for view named Index it is not fetched from my FirsApplication but from the Dll file I placed in some folder.

Any ideas on how to do that or any articles you can recomment ?

```
var moduleViewLocations = new string[]
{
   "/dropfolder/SeconApplication.Web.Views/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
};
```

Comment: You need to add the dll as a reference, then you can access the view via going through the appropriate namespaces.

Comment: I do not want to add the reference, the dll is not loaded until on run time so i can not create a reference. i load the controllers DLL and the views DLL on startup, the controller is picked up and can be used, however it can not find the Views from the DLL

Comment: Would [RazorLight](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight) be of any use?

Comment: no but i found a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

solved in core 2.1

After a lot of try and errors i found a way to use pre-compiled views from another solution.

in the starup.cs, you first need to load the DLL containing the views you have from another solution, then you simply register the assebly as embeddedFileProvider in the razor view engine.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        //load the assembly from the view dll you have
        Assembly assempbly2 = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath("C:/the/path/to/your/solution.Views.dll");

        //register the views in razor view engine 
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(assempbly2));
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    }
```